# Why when getting html code by view source code is different than using Java code?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get html content by code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {

    public static String getHtmlContent(String urlAddress) {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlAddress);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            br.close();
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlEmpik = getHtmlContent("https://myduolife.com/shop/products/1/780,duolife-keratin-hair-complex.html");
        System.out.println(urlEmpik);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I entered into this website and make (click by mouse) "view source code" on the website the HTML content is different than when I use my (above) Java code. This code works correctly for most websites, but there are some websites where it does not work I mean the HTML source code is different. I do not know what is the reason? Maybe it is connected with some special security on some websites? Thank you for help.

Comment: Haven't looked at it, but I guess they run some JavaScript when the page loads which a simple HTTP GET will not reproduce. Try accessing the site in your browser with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Maybe you are right, sounds sensible, but how to turn the Javascript in Java code? How to get HTML content using Java and with JS disabled?

Comment: You can try Selenium https://selenium.dev/

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer, and that is, generally, known as "proprietary handshakes" and "proprietary servers."  There is not that much that can be done, however there are some ways to increase the likelihood that the server's HTML response is closer to the one a programmer would get when using a browser.   Mostly, just remember that web-servers are written by developers in the real world, and many of the more popular websites fine-tune the HTML response that is received based on who is asking.  If it is a Java Program, you might be told to leave immediately.

NOTE: Learning Selenium for this can help, but Selenium has other problems and bugs - and is complicated.

ONE AVENUE THAT WORKS ON MANY SERVERS IS A "USER AGENT" (and watch if the fake-out works):

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String USER_AGENT = "Chrome/61.0.3163.100";
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you write me how can I change my Java code to make it work?